# Width property of DataGridView always returns NULL

Tags: c#, winforms, nullpointerexception

I have a `DataGridView` that I populate from a `DataSource` like:

```
this.dgvBackchecks.DataSource = db.GetTableBySQL($"exec usp_Backcheck_Get_List");
```

It works correctly, it returns columns as I want:

[image]

So I use properties of `DataGridView` to set visible false some items:

```
this.dgvBackchecks.Columns["ProjectKey"].Visible = false;
this.dgvBackchecks.Columns["DesignKey"].Visible = false;
this.dgvBackchecks.Columns["BackColor"].Visible = false;
```

It is working, problem is when I try to change `Job No` column width like:

```
this.dgvBackchecks.Columns["Job No"].Width = 45;
```

It always throw me a Null exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an 
>   instance of an object.'

To do a simple test and confirm `Job No` is not null I try to set visible of `Job No` to false as the other columns like:

```
 this.dgvBackchecks.Columns["Job No"].Visible = false;
```

And it works!, so it's not problem of column come or not in DataSource because column already exist. I really don't undertand what is the problem there.

Complete code:

```
 this.dgvBackchecks.DataSource = db.GetTableBySQL($"exec usp_Backcheck_Get_List");

            this.dgvBackchecks.Columns["ProjectKey"].Visible = false;
            this.dgvBackchecks.Columns["DesignKey"].Visible = false;
            this.dgvBackchecks.Columns["BackColor"].Visible = false;
            this.dgvBackchecks.Columns["Job No"].Visible = false; //This works
            this.dgvBackchecks.Columns["Job No"].Width = 45; //This no works
```

What is the problem with the `Width` property?

Comment: You probably do not have a column named "Job No" Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Have you read my question? I commented that I check that null using `.Visible = false` and it works, so problem is not about if I have "Job No" or not, I already confirmed that exists with that test. @NewContributor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the column `AutoSizeMode` property before setting `Width`

```
this.dgvBackchecks.Columns["Job No"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
this.dgvBackchecks.Columns["Job No"].Width = 60;
```

Comment: No problem glad to help